# Purpose of @ symbols in Python?

Tags: python

I've noticed in several examples i see things such as this:

```
# Comments explaining code i think
@innerclass
```

or:

```
def foo():
"""
 Basic Doc String
"""
@classmethod
```

Googling doesn't get me very far, for just a general definition of what this is. Also i cant find anything really in the python documentation.

What do these do?

Comment: @uberjumper - You should give the answer to abhinavg if you feel we both deserve it.  I got some free traffic to my blog and they have less rep than me anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're decorators.

`<shameless plug>`
I have a [blog post](http://jasonmbaker.wordpress.com/2009/04/25/the-magic-of-python-decorators/) on the subject.
`</shameless plug>`

Comment: Your shameless plug, was an extremely well written and clear article.

Answer (score 26):

They are called decorators. They are functions applied to other functions. Here is a copy of my answer to a similar question.

Python decorators add extra functionality to another function.
An italics decorator could be like

```
def makeitalic(fn):
    def newFunc():
        return "<i>" + fn() + "</i>"
    return newFunc
```

Note that a function is defined inside a function. What it basically does is replace a function with the newly defined one. For example, I have this class

```
class foo:
    def bar(self):
        print "hi"
    def foobar(self):
        print "hi again"
```

Now say, I want both functions to print "---" after and before they are done. I could add a print "---" before and after each print statement. But because I don't like repeating myself, I will make a decorator

```
def addDashes(fn): # notice it takes a function as an argument
    def newFunction(self): # define a new function
        print "---"
        fn(self) # call the original function
        print "---"
    return newFunction
    # Return the newly defined function - it will "replace" the original
```

So now I can change my class to

```
class foo:
    @addDashes
    def bar(self):
        print "hi"

    @addDashes
    def foobar(self):
        print "hi again"
```

For more on decorators, check http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-cpdecor.html

Comment: FYI - the other answer is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators/739667#739667

Comment: And why do you even need the 'fn' argument to addDashes if you don't use it?

Comment: I used pythontutor.com/visualize.html to really understand what is going on here. All the 'self's make it really confusing, mostly the newFunction(self) and fn(self).

Answer (score 5):

With

```
@function
def f():
    pass
```

you simply wrap `function` around `f()`. `function` is called a decorator.

It is just syntactic sugar for the following:

```
def f():
    pass
f=function(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

it is a [`decorator`](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-decorator) syntax.